# about concatenation "a||b" in Maple?

Tags: concatenation, maple

I test the code

```
    L:=[2,1];
    sum('a||b*L[1]', 'b' = 1 .. 2);
```

It returns `a1*L[1]+a2*L[1]`, but I expect to get `a1*2+a2*2` after evaluation of `L[1]`. 
Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have one further question. Here's the test code:

```
    L := [2, 1]
    test := proc (i) local a1; a1 := 1; add(a || b*L[i], b = 1 .. 2) end proc
    test(1);
```

will result
                          2 a1 + 2 a2
without evaluating `a1` which is a local variable defined in function test.
I expect to get `2*1+2*a2`. Any further idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line is just an equation, with `=`, and not an actual assignment with `:=`. So you weren't doing an assignment to `L`.

And the uneval quotes are misapplied, in the `sum` call, and wrap too much.

You could also use `add` instead of `sum`, to rely on the special evaluation rules of `add` and thus get rid of the need for the uneval quotes.

```
> L:=[2,1];                          
                              L := [2, 1]

> add(cat(a,b)*L[1], b = 1 .. 2);
                              2 a1 + 2 a2

> add((a||b)*L[1], b = 1 .. 2);  
                              2 a1 + 2 a2

> sum('a||b'*L[1], 'b' = 1 .. 2);    
                              2 a1 + 2 a2

> sum('cat(a,b)'*L[1], 'b' = 1 .. 2);
                              2 a1 + 2 a2
```

Comment: Nice, acer. Sorry for my typo for the assignment.